# Bilinear transformation confusion

Tags: z-transform, laplace-transform, bilinear-transform

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform) says in bilinear transformation from \$s\$ domain to $z$ domain relation is

$$\boxed{s \longleftarrow \frac{2}{T}\frac{z-1}{z+1}}$$

But [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnt6XwwqzXAhUIMo8KHbIlAGwQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnptel.ac.in%2Fcourses%2F108103008%2FPDF%2Fmodule3%2Fm3_lec2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0afjLdwhET28ybRcj6TEiU) this relation is given like this

$$\boxed{w=\frac{z+1}{z-1}}$$

What is difference between this two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the link which describes the second mapping
$$ w = \frac{z+1}{z-1}$$

> Thus inside of the unit circle in z-plane maps into the left half of w-plane and outside of the unit circle in z-plane maps into the right half of w-plane. **Although w-plane seems to be similar to s-plane**, quantitatively it is **not same**

It states that $w$ is not the $s$ plane.

Therefore, if your aim is in studying the bilinear transformation for **digital filter design** then you can safely use the first, well known, bilinear transformation relation, and its inverse:

$$\boxed{s \leftarrow \frac{2}{T}\frac{z-1}{z+1}}$$

Otherwise, the paper you linked is dealing with **stability** analysis of discrete-time systems using bilinear transform of its own selection...

Comment: sir for the stabilty analysis why they use a different relation? can they use this relation $\boxed{s \leftarrow \frac{2}{T}\frac{z-1}{z+1}}$ also if the w plane is not same as the s plane they can apply RH criteria?

Comment: They want to map poles from z-plane of discrete-time to w-plane of cont-time for stability analysis using RH method which applies to continuous-time systems. I don't know why they preferred such a mapping. Probably its **warping type** produces a more desired result. In the paper they describe the method. So if you want to follow **that** paper, then you should use their own notation. Morever you can check your claim by making the same analysis using the former mapping (let T=2) and see if they yield the same results.

Comment: I just used in a problem as you said they both are giving same result in terms of stability,but not sure if this can change its behaviour in other problems.anyway Thank you sir